# Is there a way to use gobuffalo i18n translator in models?

Tags: go, buffalo

gobuffalo i18n translator is accessible in actions but how can I access it on my models? It requires the `buffalo.Context` as a param in `T *i18n.Translator`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround solution.

1.In models.go create the following function

```
import "github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n/i18n"
var Lang = "en"

func t(translationID string, args ...interface{}) string{


   T, _ := i18n.Tfunc(Lang, fmt.Sprintf("locales/models.%s.yaml", Lang))
   return T(translationID,args... ) 

}
```

In your init() function add

```
    i18n.LoadTranslationFile(fmt.Sprintf("locales/models.fr.yaml"))
    i18n.LoadTranslationFile(fmt.Sprintf("locales/models.en.yaml"))
    ... other locale files if needed....
```

In your models you can now use the translate function  `t("translationID")`

You can change the models locale by simple setting the Lang variable `models.Lang="fr"`